# how to fix error Does not use passive listeners to improve scrolling performance (Lighthouse Report)

Tags: javascript, lighthouse

A recent Lighthouse Report flagged the following issue.

"Does not use passive listeners to improve scrolling performance"

How do I resolve this issue?.

```
( function( document, window, undefined ) {
var form = document.getElementById( 'form-wrapper' ),
toggle = document.querySelector( '.search-toggle' ),
close = document.getElementById( 'search-close' ),
click = 'ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
toggle.addEventListener( click, toggleSearchForm );
close.addEventListener( click, closeSearchForm );

function toggleSearchForm() {
    if ( form.classList.contains( 'is-visible' ) ) {
        closeSearchForm();
    } else {
        form.classList.add( 'is-visible' );
        form.querySelector( '.search-field' ).focus();
    }
}
function closeSearchForm() {
    form.classList.remove( 'is-visible' );
}

// Press ESC key close search form.
document.addEventListener( 'keyup', function( event ) {
    if ( 27 === event.keyCode ) {
        closeSearchForm();
    }
} );

// Sticky share button for single posts. Applied only for large screens and icon style.
if ( window.innerWidth >= 1200 && 'undefined' !== typeof StickySidebar ) {
    var adminBarHeight = document.body.classList.contains( 'admin-bar' ) ? 32 : 0,
        sharedaddy = new StickySidebar( '.entry-body .sharedaddy', {
            containerSelector: '.entry-body',
            innerWrapperSelector: '.sd-social-icon',
            topSpacing: adminBarHeight
        } );
}
```

} )( document, window );

Comment: this is likely *not* the code that is triggering that warning, but `{passive: true}` might help elsewhere (wherever you have a `scroll` event) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#improving_scrolling_performance_with_passive_listeners

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi when i delete this code, the warning not showing 
click = 'ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchstart' : 'click';

Comment: then it's the same ... add `{passive: true}` as third argument of `addEventListener`

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi I add this code "click.addEventListener('touchstart', handler, {passive: true});" but the error keep showing