# Google maps - Does not use passive listeners to improve scrolling performance

Tags: listener, lighthouse

I am building a wordpres site with a google maps iframe on each page.
When doing lighthouse report I get these errors.
js:308
js:308
init_embed.js:87
js:268
maps.googleapis.com/…tl/en_gb/util.js:58

This is the website http://nathanw70.sg-host.com/

See screenshot. When rolling over I get links to google maps. I have tried adding the code from this thread [how to fix error Does not use passive listeners to improve scrolling performance (Lighthouse Report)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65824764/how-to-fix-error-does-not-use-passive-listeners-to-improve-scrolling-performance) and also the code from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#improving_scrolling_performance_with_passive_listeners

I can not get rid of the errors.

Does not use passive listeners to improve scrolling performance
Consider marking your touch and wheel event listeners as `passive` to improve your page's scroll performance. Learn more.
Source
js:308
js:308
init_embed.js:87
js:268
maps.googleapis.com/…tl/en_gb/util.js:58

[screenshot error google maps passive listeners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h89ik.png)